# How to disable swiper button dynamically in flutter_swiper?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-swiper

I am using *flutter_swiper* to swipe images. I have two swipers as you can see i want to disable those two swiper arrows *dynamically* how can i do that?

[image]

I cant disable from start as i want to disable it when some condition is satisfied

here is some sample code:-

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  var eImage = [
    "img/eyes/1.png",
    "img/eyes/2.png",
    "img/eyes/3.png",
  ];

  double height = 200;
  int itemNo;
  double eh = 200;
  double ew = 200;
  double nh = 100;
  double nw = 300;
  double lh = 100;
  double lw = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("img/wal.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Stack(

                            children: <Widget>[
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment(0, -0.6),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: ew,
                                  height: eh,
                                  //color: Colors.purple,
                                  child: new SizedBox(
                                    child: Swiper(
                                      itemBuilder:
                                          (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                        return Image.asset(
                                          eImage[index],
                                        );
                                      },
                                      itemCount: eImage.length,
                                      itemWidth: 200,
                                      itemHeight: 200,
                                      control: new SwiperControl(),
                                      layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
                                      customLayoutOption: CustomLayoutOption(
                                          startIndex: 1, stateCount: 3) ///<--- here i am trying to start from 1st index
                                          .addRotate([
                                        0 / 180,
                                        0.0,
                                        0 / 180
                                      ]).addTranslate([
                                        Offset(-400.0, 0.0),
                                        Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                                        Offset(370, -40.0),
                                      ]),
                                    ),
                                    height: 200,
                                    width: 350,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ))));
                      }
  }
```

Now i want to disable those arrows with help of a function which will be triggered at particular event

Comment: what you mean by dynamically??. you just don't want to show swiper buttons? right . Also, can you add Swiper code.

Comment: @chetansuri  i am new to flutter so don't have much idea. i am swiping different images. when i press next button i want to disable those swiper arrows so that i can take widget snapshot without arrows. i have big code but i can post a small amount of code for single swiper

Comment: you must have some code for this. please add it in your questions

Comment: @chetansuri done!! you can check now

Comment: can you try removing this line in your code  control: new SwiperControl(),

Comment: @chetansuri i want it to swipe images. so i cant remove it. i want to disable it when i trigger some event

Comment: you can still swipe even if there is no swiper button.

Comment: @chetansuri i know i cant remove swiper button because everything in the above image is using swiper eyes,nose,lips so if i remove buttons then everything will get ambiguous as if user will try to swipe lips he will end up swiping lower face

Comment: @chetansuri so i have disabled normal swipe in these two and enabled buttons. i can't put whole code here so i have put just some sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found solution by disabling  `iconPrevious:` and `iconNext:` at run time with help of a boolean flag. If flag is false then enable buttons and disable if flag is true.

Example:

```
var disable=false;
```

Here this is flag which will allow swiper button to get displayed if the value is false

Now, set flag in controller

```
control: new SwiperControl(
                                 iconPrevious: disable?null:Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                                 iconNext:disable?null:Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                               ),
```

Change the flag using set state in button.

```
 next(){
    setState(() {
      disable=true;
    });
}
```